# add an effect when nav menu is displayed from hover

Tags: html, css, hover

I need to add an effect for my mobile where the menu is display smoothly when the navigation button is hovered.

what I need is that the menu should display with ease not sudden appearance and if its possible not to adjust the content of my site like overlapping the content above if plausible

CSS

```
.menuimg:hover + #navcontainer {
    display: block;
    height: auto;
}

#navcontainer:hover {
    display: block;
    height: auto;
}

.children {
    display: none;
}

#navcontainer {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    display: block;
    float: none;
    width: 100%;
    height: 20px;
    list-style: none;
    text-align: center;
}

.menu {
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    width: auto;
    text-align: left;
}

#navcontainer ul {
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
    text-align: left;
}

#navcontainer ul li {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 0;
    padding: 0 6px;
}

#navcontainer ul li a {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    padding: .2em 1em;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #694a31;
    border-top: 1px solid transparent;
    border-right: 1px solid transparent;
    border-left: 1px solid transparent;
    background-color: transparent;
}

#navcontainer ul li ul li {
    display: block;
    float: none;
    width: auto;
    margin-left: 0;
    border-top: 1px solid #e3d7be;
    background: #edebd7;
}

#navcontainer ul li ul li a {
    opacity: 1 !important;
    color: #724e32;
    border-top: 0 !important;
    border-right: 0 !important;
    border-left: 0 !important;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0 0 0 0 !important;
    -moz-border-radius: 0 0 0 0 !important;
    border-radius: 0 0 0 0 !important;
    background: transparent !important;
    background-color: transparent !important;
}

#navcontainer li:hover ul,
#navcontainer li:active ul {
    display: block;
}

#navcontainer ul li:hover a {
    opacity: .5;
    color: #724e32;
    border-top: 1px solid #694b0a;
    border-right: 1px solid #694b0a;
    border-left: 1px solid #694b0a;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
    border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
    background-color: #edebd7;
}

#navcontainer ul li a:hover {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #d3c096;
}

#navcontainer li:hover ul.children,
#navcontainer li:active ul.children {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 300;
    top: auto;
    overflow: visible;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    padding: 5px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    color: #724e32;
    border-right: 1px solid #694b0a;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #694b0a;
    border-left: 1px solid #694b0a;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;
    border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;
    background: #edebd7;
}

#navcontainer ul li ul li:hover {
    margin-left: 0;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #d3c096;
}

#navcontainer ul li ul li a:hover {
    margin-left: 0;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #d3c096;
}

#navcontainer ul li ul li:hover a {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: transparent;
}
```

I want is to appear my menu at easy like from fading transition when i hovered on the navigation button
http://prntscr.com/4yverw

i have tested my css on fiddle its working fine there but when i transfer it to my site the menu transition doesn't work change and addeds some

```
  .menu { display:none > opacity:0 
     -webkit-transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in-out;
    transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in-out;}
.menuimg:hover + .menu
    {
        display: block; height: auto;   opacity: 1;
     -webkit-transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in-out;
    transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in-out;
    }.menu:hover
    {
   opacity: 1;
     -webkit-transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in-out;
    transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in-out;        display: block;    height: auto;

    }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/xeqcx1zL/1/ - workign trasition
i changed the code 
original code

```
.menuimg:hover + #navcontainer 
#navcontainer:hover
```

to this

```
.menuimg:hover + .menu 
.menu:hover
```

---

I have now my transition menu the only problem is that since i remove the display:none; the menu is always their but you cant see it since its on opacity:0; i want to hide it so it doesnt eats a space on my site, but using the display none and block css the transition wont work.

the menu is displayed under the button but you cant see it. it should be activated if you hover your mouse on the button.

http://prntscr.com/4z4jah

Comment: `SHOW ME THE CODE`, if you want help, here its no a place for request somebody do your job, this is a place where you ask specific questions and get a specific answer, what part of you code its not working??

Comment: i forgot to put the css my bad
heres the sample 
http://jsfiddle.net/xeqcx1zL/

Comment: research for css transition. start with http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/t/transition/

Comment: I found something that match what I want to. 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22313438/css-image-hover-transition-not-working-with-display-none-displayblock-and-i

http://jsfiddle.net/Gy6BE/ - with transition
http://jsfiddle.net/46AKc/65/ - w/o transition

just gonna convert mine using this guide